# Generate PDF with Cyrillic letters using IText

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, pdf-generation, itext7

I want to generate in SpringBoot pdf file from html with styles and with using cyrillic letters. Is there any solution so that I could convert html file as it is to pdf, including cyrillic alphabet and style?

```
 @GetMapping("/generatePDF")
    public void generateInvoice(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){

        try (OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);

            Context context = new Context();
            context.setVariable("user", userService.findUserById(1L));

            String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("welcome", context);

            Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
            document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
            document.outputSettings().charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            String modifiedHtml = document.html().replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("src/main/java/com/example/textpdf/Arial Unicode MS.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            renderer.setDocumentFromString(modifiedHtml);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and welcome.html file:

```
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h3 style="text-align: center; color: green">
    <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal;color: blue" th:text="'Привіт '+ ${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"></span>
</h3>
<h2>Привет</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to use Paragraph class but it doesn't add styles of html file.